# Unable to import sql file in pgadmin4 on windows

Tags: postgresql-9.6, pgadmin-4

I'm trying to import sql file in pgadmin4 using psql command in windows but it returns "The system cannot find the path specified." I tried to restore database by using pgadmin but it does not work.

Please help me.

[image: error image]

[image: error image]
[image: error image]

Comment: That screenshot has nothing to do with either `psql` or `pg_restore`. And it has absolutely nothing to do with pgAdmin which is a GUI tool, not a command line tool.

Comment: Sorry! I mistakenly uploaded wrong image. @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: `psql` is also not "pgAdmin" - but apparently there is no file `d:\backup8.sql`. What does `dir d:\b*` show you?

Comment: Yes, there is backup8.sql file in D drive but still it returns there is no file. @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: I have added image of contents od d drive. @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: That screenshot shows a file `backup8`, not a file named `backup8.sql`

Comment: That is sql file.@a_horse_with_no_name

Answer (score 1):

Maybe...
1. Remove the "cd" command from beginning
2. Put the backup file other than root dir
3. Try to run your command in the terminal
4. Show me the terminal's substance

Comment: I removed the cd but it still gave me same error. I have changed the image in the question.@kjt